# Changing iterated variable list inside for loop in Python

Tags: python, list, loops, for-loop

I have the following problem: I am trying to edit the variables x and y if they are of the wrong data type

```
for i in [x,y]:
    if (type(i) == np.ndarray) == True:
         i = np.ndarray.tolist(i)
```

but once the loop is ended, the variables x and y stay of the same data type as before the loop, essentially the values that the I receives at each iteration stays in that temporary memory space defined for the for loop.

Comment: don't dynamically modify variables. **Use a container** then modify that container (or create a new container, e.g. using a list comprehension)

Comment: "the values that the (i) receives at each iteration stays in that temporary memory space defined for the for loop." There is no "temporary memory space". It's just that you are assigning to the variable `i`, not to the variables `x` or `y`.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga how do i use containers, first time hearing about them

Comment: like a `list` or a `dict`. a data structure

Answer (score 0):

As **juanpa.arrivillaga** wrote - "use a container"

```py
z = [x,y]
for j,i in enumerate(z):
    if type(i) == np.ndarray:
         z[j] = list(i)
[x,y] = z
```

And don't use `type(<obj>) == <type>`, user `isinstance`

```py
z = [x,y]
for j,i in enumerate(z):
    if isinstance(i, np.ndarray):
         z[j] = list(i)
[x,y] = z
```

Or use one line command

```py
z = [x,y]
z = [list(v) if isinstance(v, np.ndarray) else v for v in z]
[x,y] = z
```

And in your example

```py
[x,y] = [list(v) if isinstance(v, np.ndarray) else v for v in [x,y]]
```